# how to update sheet names in vba by cell value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the following code in VBA which is working fine but I need a way to change the "sheets(array(......)" part to  make it more user friendly.

I want to have a link to a cell or range of cells so a user can update it without the need to go into VBA

```vb
Sub ExportAsPDF()
   Dim FolderPath As String
   
   Sheets(Array("4", "5", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "14", "15", "17", "18", "19", _
                "21", "22", "24", "25", "29", "30", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", _
                "39", "40", "41", "43", "44", "47", "48", "50", "51", "52", "54", "55", _
                "57", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "67", "68", "69", "70", "72", _
                "75", "76", "77", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", _
                "88", "89", "90", "92", "93", "94", "101", "102", "104", "105", "106", _
                "107", "108", "109")).Select
                
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=Range("A1") + "All FV.pdf", _
                                   openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
   Sheets("Figures").Select
   ActiveWorkbook.Save
   MsgBox "All PDF's have been successfully exported."
End Sub
```

The sheet "figures" is not selected during the export, and the numbers are not consecutive some are missing.

Cell A1 on all the selected sheets has the destination folder in it for another code that runs on the same sheet.

The list of sheet numbers is already on the "Figures" sheet is there any way that this can be used? from A4:A78.

TIA

i have not tried anything yet as unsure what to use.

Comment: Is the folder path in `A1`? Is there any connection between the folder path and the workbook containing the sheets (hopefully also containing this code)? On which sheet is `A1` located? How will the code be run e.g. by clicking on a button? Have you decided in which column of which worksheet will the names be located? What is the first cell e.g. `B2`? Will there be charts? Will there be (very) hidden sheets? Please edit your question and add more detail.

Comment: Cell A1 does contain the destination folder, the code is run by a button click. There is only one hidden sheet that contains formulas. no charts etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep sheet name in any column (ie. column C).

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim shtNames, sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("Figures")
    shtNames = Application.Transpose(sht.Cells(1, 3).CurrentRegion.Value)
    For i = 1 To UBound(shtNames)
        shtNames(i) = CStr(shtNames(i)) 'Covert Sheet name to a string
    Next
    Sheets(shtNames).Select
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Trainee1\Desktop\PDFs"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sht.Range("A1") + "All FV.pdf", _
        openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
    sht.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    MsgBox "All PDF's have been successfully exported."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of sheets on a worksheet and use this to create the sheet array

```
    Sub MakeArraySheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ArraySheets() As String
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheets("SheetList") 'name of sheet with the sheet names in column A
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells


        ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(x)
        ArraySheets(x) = c
        x = x + 1
        
    Next c

    Sheets(ArraySheets).Select

'    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
'                                    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
'                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
'                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True



End Sub
```